# How can one calculate the co-normal (disjunctive/or) product of two graphs in Wolfram Language?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorica

I'm trying to verify a result in Wolfram Cloud. The standard cartesian graph product is implemented. Graph join is implemented. But it seems that the co-normal product does not seem to be, and honestly as easy as it should be to code the function myself, I have no idea where to begin.

I'm really new with the language, so I don't even know how I would code a function that would create a new graph, where there's an edge between (a, b) and (c, d) iff there's an edge between a and c or between b and d.

Comment: Do you mean [that definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_product)?

Comment: Yes, the co-normal product as defined there, or in other words, what I stated above as (a, b) ~ (c, d) iff a ~ c or b ~ d.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in [this Community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3070070), the conormal/disjunctive product can be implemented like so for unweighted graphs:

```
conormalProduct[g1_?GraphQ, g2_?GraphQ, opts : OptionsPattern[GraphProduct]] := 
 With[{m1 = AdjacencyMatrix[g1], m2 = AdjacencyMatrix[g2]},
  AdjacencyGraph[Mod[KroneckerProduct[m1, ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[m2]]] +
     KroneckerProduct[ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[m1]], m2] + 
     KroneckerProduct[m1, m2], 2], opts]]
```

Using kglr's example,

```
g1 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}];
g2 = Graph[{a <-> b, c <-> a}];
conormalProduct[g1, g2, EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc"]
```

[image: disjunctive product]

In fact, the disjunctive product is actually built-in as `GraphProduct[g1, g2, "Conormal"]`, but the internal implementation seems to be quite a bit slower.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with. It's messy, but it seems to work. I'm sure someone would be able to do a better implementation. I don't even know how to store a result so I don't have to type out `cpF[cpF[VertexList[g1], VertexList[g2]],cpF[VertexList[g1], VertexList[g2]]]`, nor can I figure out why Cartesian Product of a list isn't working normally, thus why I used the `cpF` function that I found somewhere else.

```
cpF = Distribute[{##}, List] &;

edgeQS[g_, e : {_, _}] := Or @@ (EdgeQ[g, #] & /@ {DirectedEdge @@ e, 
     DirectedEdge @@ Reverse[e], UndirectedEdge @@ e});

edgeBetweenQ[g1_, g2_, e1_, e2_]:= {e1<-> e2, edgeQS[g1, {e1[[1]], e2[[1]]}] || edgeQS[g2, {e1[[2]], e2[[2]]}]};

samePairQ[e1_, e2_] := e1 === e2 || e1 === Reverse[e2];

coedges[g1_, g2_] := Map[edgeBetweenQ[g1, g2, #[[1]] , #[[2]]]&, cpF[cpF[VertexList[g1], VertexList[g2]],cpF[VertexList[g1], VertexList[g2]]]];

conorm[g1_, g2_] :=  Graph[DeleteDuplicates[Map[#[[1]] &, Select[coedges[g1, g2],#[[2]] &]], samePairQ]];
```

Comment: +1. I test it at `conorm[Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}], 
 Graph[{a \[UndirectedEdge] b, c \[UndirectedEdge] a}]]`. A good code is a commented code. You wrote "can I figure out why Cartesian Product of a list isn't working normally". I think there is a conflikt between the Combinatorica package and WL.

Comment: No idea how to even use comments in Wolfram Language. I selected Wolfram simply because it had useful graph operations, and I assumed co-normal product would be in there already. But apparently not!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like:

```
ClearAll[coNormalProduct]
coNormalProduct[g__?UndirectedGraphQ, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := 
 RelationGraph[Or @@ MapThread[EdgeQ, {{g}, UndirectedEdge @@@ Transpose[{##}]}] &, 
  Tuples[VertexList /@ {g}], opts, EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc"]
```

***Example:***

```
g1 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}]; 
g2 = Graph[{a <-> b, c <-> a}];

coNormalProduct[g1, g2]
```

[image]

```
coNormalProduct[g1, g2, g1, ImageSize -> Large, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wolfram Language enough to be sure, but does seem like it. Much more concise than what I provided.